# git worktrees vs "clone --reference"

Tags: git, git-worktree

What are the pros-cons of using git worktrees vs maintaining multiple clones with `--reference` flag? The main scenario I am considering is when a developer needs to maintain multiple git repositories on the disk for old releases (release/1.0, release/2.0, release/3.0) because switching branches on a single git repo and rebuilding would be costly.

Using worktrees the developer could have a single clone of the repo, and any old releases could be created as worktrees of the repo using `cd /opt/main/`, `git worktree add /opt/old_release_1 release/1.0`. Using reference clones, the developer maintains a main clone somewhere, and uses `cd /opt/old_release_1`, `git clone --reference /opt/main/.git ssh://git@github.com/myrepo.git` to create clone repositories for the old releases.

It seems like they can both accomplish the same goal. Are there benefits to one over the other in terms of speed, disk space... other things?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They all have a few issues that matter, but using `git worktree` is probably going to be your best bet.

- A clone, let's call this *AD* for after-dependency clone, made *with* `--reference local-path` but *without* `--dissociate` uses objects from *`local-path`*.  By "objects", I mean literal Git objects (stored loosely and/or in pack files).  The other Git repository—the one in *`local-path`*—has no idea that *AD* is using these.

  Let's call the base clone *BC*.  Now, suppose something happens in *BC* so that an object is no longer needed, such as deleting a branch name or a remote-tracking name.  At this point, a `git gc` run in *BC* may garbage-collect and delete the object.

  If you now switch to the *AD* clone and run various Git operations, they may fail due to the removed object.  The problem is that the older *BC* clone has no idea that the newer *AD* clone depends on it.

  Note that *AD* has, embedded in it, the path name of *BC*.  If you move *BC* you must edit the `.git/objects/info/alternates` file in *AD*.
- A work-tree made with `git worktree add` also uses objects from the original clone.  Let's still call the original clone *BC*, with the added work-trees just called *W<sub>b</sub>*.  There are two key differences from the BC/AD setup above:

  - Each new work-tree *W<sub>b</sub>* literally uses the entire `.git` directory from *BC*.
  - The *BC* repository records the path of each *W<sub>b</sub>*, so it knows about each *W<sub>b</sub>*.  You won't have the problem of objects disappearing unexpectedly.
  - However, since *BC* records each *W<sub>b</sub>* and all the branch names actually live inside *BC* itself, there's a constraint imposed: whatever branch is checked out in *BC* cannot be checked out in any *W<sub>b</sub>*.  Moreover, *W<sub>b1</sub>* must be "on" (as in `git status` says `on branch ...`) a different branch than *W<sub>b2</sub>*, and so on.  (You can be in "detached HEAD" mode, i.e., not on any branch at all, in any or all of *BC* and each *W<sub>b</sub>*.)

  Since *BC* records each *W<sub>b</sub>* path (and vice versa), if you want to *move* any of these repositories, you must adjust the paths.

Comment: I think what you have written in your first bullet point regarding invalidating references in AD and creating problems there applies to `--shared`, but not to `--reference`.

Comment: @Sunday: I've done this in practice (back in 2016 or so) and those problems do actually occur with `--reference`. Using `--dissociate` fixes them, at the expense of a lot more disk space being used.

Comment: Yes you are right, it applies to both, sorry. I checked [the git clone reference](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt--s) again and the paragraph about `--reference` also refers to the warning note that is present in the paragraph about `--shared`.

Comment: @Sunday: I ended up using `--dissociate` in the code I left for the company. Not sure they ended up installing it, even though it cut a full build from 2 hours to 15 minutes. :-)